# Visual Basic If Not Issue

Tags: vb.net, exception, loops

I am doing my homework for my visual basic class.  I have most of the code written and everything seems to be working well except for my If Not statement that catches the exception when the loop does not find what it is looking for.  Anyone see a problem with the way the code looks.  The file is loaded in using the browse button already and it works find when I enter information that the loop can find.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   
System.EventArgs)

Handles btnSearch.Click
    'event level variables
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Integer

    'looks for entry match
    If rdoAbbrev.Checked = True Then
        Do Until Found Or Counter > 257
            If Country(Counter).Abbreviation.ToUpper = txtAbbrev.Text.ToUpper Then
                Found = True
                txtCountry.Text = Country(Counter).Names
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        Do Until Found Or Counter > 257
            If Country(Counter).Names.ToUpper = txtCountry.Text.ToUpper Then
                Found = True
                txtAbbrev.Text = Country(Counter).Abbreviation
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Loop
        If Not Found Then
            MessageBox.Show("This is not a valid entry.", "NO MATCH FOUND", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If rdoAbbrev.Checked = True Then
                txtAbbrev.Text = ""
                txtAbbrev.Focus()
            Else
                txtCountry.Text = ""
                txtCountry.Focus()

            End If
        End If
    End If
    'match not found response

    'reset variables
    Counter = 0
    Found = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the problem that it's not finding what you expect to find? I would just load a smaller file and step thru it with the debugger to see why it's not matching. The searching code is probably right since you can enter values and find them. The loading/parsing part is probably leaving a leading space or comma or something in the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `If Not Found` block only occurs if `rdoAbbrev.Checked = True`. Is that what you intended? If not, then that block of code should either be located outside of the first `If` block (below it) or you should have a second `If` block after the first `While` loop.

**EDIT**
It looks like Country is an array. You should probably use `Counter >= Country.Length`.

Arrays in VB.NET are 0-based. Meaning that the first item is located at `Country(0)`, the second item is at `Country(1)`, etc. If there are 100 elements in the array, then the last element is located at `Country(99)`. `Country(100)` does not exist and will cause an Exception if you try to access it.

I'm not sure what the requirements of your homework are, but usually to iterate over the elements of a collection (array, list, etc), you would use a For loop. You can jettison from the loop early with the Exit command.

```
For Counter As Integer = 0 To Country.Length - 1
     '...Country(Counter)
     If Found Then Exit For
Next
```

Comment: I have moved the block of code outside of the if statement and it still does not work.  If I enter valid data everything works fine because it does not have to jump to the if not statement.  but if i enter invalid data it throws an exception to the "If Country(Counter).Names.ToUpper = txtCountry.Text.ToUpper Then" lines but halts the program instead of jumping to my if not found statement

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the "Not Found" part to execute regardless of the `rdoAbbrev.Checked` property, it looks like a slight error in your logic (easily fixed).

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    'event level variables
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Integer

    'looks for entry match
    If rdoAbbrev.Checked = True Then
        Do Until Found Or Counter > 257
            If Country(Counter).Abbreviation.ToUpper = txtAbbrev.Text.ToUpper Then
                Found = True
                txtCountry.Text = Country(Counter).Names
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
            'You could also write this as:
            'Found = Country(Counter).Abbreviation.ToUpper = txtAbbrev.Text.ToUpper
            'If Found Then
            '    txtCountry.Text = Country(Counter).Names
            'Else
            '    Counter += 1
            'End If
        Loop
    Else
        Do Until Found Or Counter > 257
            If Country(Counter).Names.ToUpper = txtCountry.Text.ToUpper Then
                Found = True
                txtAbbrev.Text = Country(Counter).Abbreviation
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
            'You could also write this as:
            'Found = Country(Counter).Names.ToUpper = txtCountry.Text.ToUpper
            'If Found Then
            '    txtAbbrev.Text = Country(Counter).Abbreviation
            'Else
            '    Counter += 1
            'End If
        Loop
    End If
    'match not found response
    'Move your "Not Found" here so that the not found works regardless of the rdoAbbrev.Checked property.
    If Not Found Then
        MessageBox.Show("This is not a valid entry.", "NO MATCH FOUND", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        If rdoAbbrev.Checked = True Then
            txtAbbrev.Text = ""
            txtAbbrev.Focus()
        Else
            txtCountry.Text = ""
            txtCountry.Focus()

        End If
    End If

    'reset variables
    Counter = 0
    Found = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should End the If statements within their range in the code and avoid ending all your If statements at the end of the code lines. usually works for me in Basic. I think that Basic has a lot of advantages, but for me it still not a high level language that has some problems because it is so easy to work with.